# How to not have tags in vue-multiselect?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-multiselect

I am using vue-multiselect and I copied the example [vue-multiselect multiple select](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-multiple-select)

```
<div>
  <label class="typo__label">Simple select / dropdown</label>
  <multiselect v-model="value" :options="options" :multiple="true" :close-on-select="false" :clear-on-select="false" :preserve-search="true" placeholder="Pick some" label="name" track-by="name" :preselect-first="true">
    <template slot="selection" slot-scope="{ values, search, isOpen }"><span class="multiselect__single" v-if="values.length &amp;&amp; !isOpen">{{ values.length }} options selected</span></template>
  </multiselect>
  <pre class="language-json"><code>{{ value  }}</code></pre>
</div>
```

In the example it can be seen that the tags are not present, this happens in all examples, by default the tagging its not present in any example.

[image]

But when using the code of the example the tagging does show,

- i tried using `:taggable="false"`,
- i tried using `<template #tag></template>`
- I also inspected, and it's not CSS hiding it
  the tags are still showing.
  [image]
  [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-multiselect-no-tags-nuhsh?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) its the minimal code to reproduce the issue.

The Desired behaviour its to not show the tagging just like in the examples.

Comment: Could you show us a little more code, preferably a minimal, reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @samu i did, https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-multiselect-no-tags-nuhsh?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `<template slot="tag">{{ '' }}</template>` to hide the tags.

Comment: This worked, but it feels unclean, i am not sure why the component doesnt have a property to just do this.

Comment: You can either raise an issue to the author on Github, or fix the issue and then make a PR to benefit all future developers.

Comment: finally! Spend at least hour to figure out how to do this and then found this answer. Thank you very much.